# Jenkins "git command not found"

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a project where build script using some git operations but my job fzailing due to it.

I have added git executable in slave's tools locations(`using following combinations`) but it's still failing

```
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin
  'C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe"
  'C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe'
```

[image]

```
java --version
git --version
```

**Java worked but git failing with Error :-**

```
"JAVA VERSION >>>>>>>>>>>>>>"
java version "1.6.0_18"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_18-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 16.0-b13, mixed mode)

"GIT VERSION >>>>>>>>>>>>>>"
'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 0):

User `jenkins` has to have access to `git`. Log in to `jenkins` account, and check whether git is available, by `which git`.

Comment: it's windows machine, I have login and checked `git --version`. it's working

Answer (score 0):

Update youe system's **Environment variables** with your installed **Git home path**.

-> 1st try manually in the system. just check if it is working or not.

other option (Which is working out for me so far)

-> **Reinstall** Git in your user account.

Comment: Yep, That's the first thing I have tried and manually `git --version` working fine on that machine.

Comment: uptate your tool location as below:                                                                        Name - (Git) Default ,home - git.exe location

Comment: just try with different directory. this "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe" having space. just move your Git into "C:\Git" then try...hope it will work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84990/discussion-between-swapnil-and-mahi).

Answer (score 0):

Try define path as `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git`